# Choose a random variable from a list on button press in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a Windows Forms Application where I want to be able to show a messagebox with a random variable from a list on button press. I made a class called SetRandomCode which sets up the list and *hopefully* sets a random number to the variable 'testVariable.' I'm fairly new to c# so I may be going about this the completely wrong way but here's my code:

**SetRandomCode.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public class SetRandomCode
    {
        List<string> randomCodes = new List<string>();

        public void setCode()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(randomCodes.Count);
            string testVariable = randomCodes[index];
            randomCodes.Add("Test");
            randomCodes.Add("Test 2");
            randomCodes.Add("Test 3");
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(testVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is 'the name 'testVariable' does not exist in the current context.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: your `testVariable` is declared in the scope of `setCode` and can only be used there.

Comment: Also, looking at your code you are getting a value from `randomCodes` via `string testVariable = randomCodes[index];`, but then you're populating the list in the next lines. You want to first populate the list, then select values from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the class in SetRandomCode static

```
public static class SetRandomCode
{

    public static string setCode()
    {
        List<string> randomCodes = new List<string>();
        randomCodes.Add("Test");
        randomCodes.Add("Test 2");
        randomCodes.Add("Test 3");
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(0, randomCodes.Count);
        return randomCodes[index];
    }
}
```

and then in form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string testVariable = SetRandomCode.setCode();
        MessageBox.Show(testVariable);
    }
}
```

A few other differences in the code is that the list is populated before you count it, otherwise the returned value will always be 0, the list is also populated before you get a value from it to avoid errors.

In this new code, test variable is being set in Form1 instead of in your **entirely separate** class. By being static, the class can have its methods called without being instantiated, allowing for the closest thing to what you were trying before

Comment: Your method is `setCode()` yet you're calling it with `setCode(randomCodes);`

Comment: @rbm my bad, I meant to have it take the list as input, thanks

Comment: And it still doesn't make sense - you are passing in an empty list and then returning a string...

Comment: @rbm The list is passed, then populated in the method, which returns the string to show in the messagebox, where is your issue? This allows for the extra strings to be added to an already existing list

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre if the list is only used in the `setCode` then that function is the only one that should know about it. *(Al trough it works, it's not logical to pass in an empty list, at least in this example)*

Comment: @Jim I thought it was best to make it adaptable so that if they plan to put in a list with values already in it, they can. Though I understand where you're coming from

Comment: It makes no sense to pass an empty list if it will only ever be empty when you pass it and be the only list used by the method you're passing it into.

Comment: Hi Alfie, thanks for this, and thanks Jim for the comments regarding the empty list being passed, that was confusing me slightly but with the updated answer this makes much more sense!

Comment: one more comment - you'd probably want to initialize the list in the constructor and not every time you call the method.

Comment: @rbm do you mean having `string testVariable = SetRandomCode.setCode();` outside of the button1_click method?

Comment: No, in `SetRandomCode` the `List<string> randomCodes` should be initialized in constructor or have the list as private (and static) property and your `setCode()` method should get values from it. If you had a list of million items, you wouldn't want to initialize _every_ time you want to get a random value - you initialize it once, and then get a random string from it.